# Fetching an array value and removing it

Tags: php

So I have this array:

```
$arr = ('a' => 343, 'b' => 34, 'c' => 65, 'd' => 465);
```

which could also be

```
$arr = ('a' => 343, 'b' => 34, 'c' => 65);
```

Can the following code be improved into one line?

```
if(isset($arr['d'])) $something = $arr['d'];
unset($arr['d']);
```

Comment: What is your goal? To always remove elements called 'd'? Or to have a maximum of 3 key / values?

Comment: yes, to remove 'd' keys

Answer (score 4):

```
if(isset($arr['d'])) $something = $arr['d'];
unset($arr['d']);
```

Well... If `arr['d']` is not set, then you don't need to unset it. So this will save an unnecessary call sometimes:

```
if(isset($arr['d']))
{
    $something = $arr['d'];
    unset($arr['d']);
}
```

If you don't care for `$something`, then you can just do

```
unset($arr['d']);
```

Which is then one line. You could also write

```
if (isset($arr['d']) && ($something = $arr['d']) !== null) unset($ar['d']);
```

That is one line as well, but will fail to do what you like if `$something` is `null`. And from the point of readability it's questionable whether this is an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to squash it into one line *and* keep it readable in any way.

```
$something = isset($arr['d'])
           ? $arr['d']
           : null;
unset($arr['d']);
```

This is just a minor enhancement, I know, but I think if one is familiar with the ternary operator its slightly better readable. At the end I don't think there is anything more optimizable.

Answer (score 0):

No reason why you can't right your own function to do this, obviously the function itself is more than 1 line but will make it a lot easier to use if you're calling it multiple times in your project.

```
function getValue(&$array, $key) {
    $value = isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;
    unset($array[$key]);
    return $value;
}

$arr = array('a' => 343, 'b' => 34, 'c' => 65, 'd' => 465);

$val = getValue($arr, 'd');
```

If you `var_dump` the two variables it will give you

```
// $val
int 465
// $arr
array
  'a' => int 343
  'b' => int 34
  'c' => int 65
```

If the key does not exist `$val` will simply be `NULL`.